# Meaning of "going to" in sentence

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

*But I'm not **going to** stand here and take all the credit myself. Because we're a team.*

Is the sentence natural with **going to**? Does the sentence mean that he doesn't **want** to take all the credit himself?

Answer (score 1):

It means that ***he has no intention to*** do so. He means that the whole team deserves credit, it is not only his merit.

See [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-be-going-to-i-am-going-to-work) the uses of the phrase ***to be going to***.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sentence is correct and quite idiomatic.

The phrase "going to" is a prediction of a future event or action.  In this case the speaker is stating that he will not take all the credit because he wants to acknowledge that his team was responsible.